# how to change android default printing dialog paper size?

Tags: android, android-print-framework

> I am using default android printer in my application i have followed this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) to print the web view.
>
> it gets printing but my problem is when the print dialog opens the default page size is A4 , it is possible to change the paper size to A5 as default?? i tried in google but i can't find the answer, can anyone help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> After searching lot i got the answer , you have to change the PrinterAttributes Refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.MediaSize.html#ISO_A5)
>
> And i android code change is

```
 PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
 builder.setMediaSize( PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A5);
 PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, builder.build());
```

> That's it.

Comment: how to do it if I don't print using print framework ?